# What would web3.js respond with in this case?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, transactions, blockchain

I have a mapping to a struct in my contract

```
mapping (uint=> Student) students;

struct Student {
    bool passed;
}
```

Now I want to call a particular student with a particular ID to see if he has passed a course or not. I'll do that using

```
students[ID].passed
```

Which is ok. What I want to know is that if the student passed the course at a later point of time, and I assign the same ID to a new block, what would

```
students[ID].passed
```

return?

Answer (score 1):

> I assign the same ID to a new block

You don't assign storage/state to blocks. Blocks are only for ordering transactions that (may) change the state. The state itself is persistent. So, `student[ID].passed` is whatever you set it to previously, `false` by default.

You probably need a more intricate data layout but I don't want to stray too far from the question raised.

Hope it helps.

p.s. A web3.js client will respond with the state at the latest/highest block it knows about.